# Timed out in waitForElementToBeRemoved only on pipeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I'm encountering a problem with my unit tests when running them on CircleCI. Locally, all tests pass successfully 100% of the time without any flakiness, but in the CircleCI pipeline, the tests randomly fail. The error message that I receive is:

`Timed out in waitForElementToBeRemoved`

I'm not sure why this is happening, as everything seems to work perfectly fine locally. I've tried running the tests multiple times on CircleCI, but the issue persists.

Here are some more details about my setup:

I'm using:

- @testing-library/react v14.0.0
- React v18.2.0
- create-react-app v5.0.1
- node:16.17

Any help or suggestions on how to debug this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two common problems with tests that fail randomly because of `waitForElementToBeRemoved`:

1. The element has already been removed before `waitForElementToBeRemoved` is called
2. The element isn't removed within the [default 1000ms timeout](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor)

**How can I reproduce this locally?**

One way you can reproduce flakiness would be to run your tests in parallel.  This will increase utilization, making free resources scarce, and should allow you to confirm that the flakiness is related to conditions like these.  You can brute force this by running your tests in multiple terminals or by using something like [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all).

**What can I do to address these issues?**

In this situation, I avoid `waitForElementToBeRemoved` and instead use `waitFor` with a longer `timeout`:

```
    waitFor(() => expect(element).not.toBeInTheDocument(), {
        timeout: 3000,
    });
```

This helps address the issues cited above:

1. Using `waitFor` in this manner will allow tests to pass if the element is no longer in the document when `waitFor` is excecuted.
2. Specifying a longer `timeout` than the 1000ms default should provide slower tests with the extra time they need to pass.